# how to access more than one filed from one model to another model

Tags: python, django

I want to use the two variables `asset_name` and `asset_image` from the model `asset_details`

```
class asset_details(models.Model):
    asset_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100 )
    asset_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media/assets',verbose_name='Asset Images',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.asset_name
```

to another model 'test' in the same app

```
class test (models.Model):
    signal_title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    asset = models.ForeignKey(asset_details,related_name="_name", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    asset_image = models.ForeignKey(asset_details,related_name="_image", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

i am not able to use the `asset_image` from `asset_details` model , all what i am getting is the `asset_name` from the model `asset_details` .i want to use the `asset_image` as well, what are the changes required in the above models ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to have two foreign keys to the same model. You should just have one and you will have access to all the fields of the model. For example, you would have access to `asset_details.asset_name` as well as `asset_details.asset_image`.

Comment: Give an example of how you want to access these fields in your views

Comment: i want to assign the fields of model test as follows -  asset(of model test) = asset_name(from model asset_details)  and asset_image (of model test) = asset_image